# Best way to check if picture already seen

Tags: android, django

My Android app grabs random pictures from a Django server. And in my app, you can vote on the picture.

I want to be able to make sure the user never gets the same picture twice. I already am saving an `array of integers` that has the `picture id` locally on the app itself.

My question is, what would be the best/good practice to have the server send only new pictures that haven't been voted on?

I was thinking of sending the server the array of integers so that the server can cross check and send back one that wasn't already voted on, but thinking this could be a problem on a larger scale -> making the server do too many computations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Django, but either you need to do as you suggested, or you can ask for a random picture, the server responds with the ID it intends to send and your app replies with either yes or no depending on whether it wants that one.  The server then either offers another random ID or you accept the picture and it sends it.

Also, use a set instead of an array - you have no interest in order, you just want to avoid duplicates.